# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/text/StrLookup

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

The error is pointing to `EventUnitTesting.readPropertyFile(EventUnitTesting.java:168)` in which the body of `readPropertyFile()` is

```
private void readPropertyFile() throws IOException, ConfigurationException{

    file = new File(fileLocation + unitTestingFileName);
    propertiesConfiguration = new PropertiesConfiguration(file);

    List<Object> propertyKeysList = propertiesConfiguration.getList("regular");
    Iterator<Object> propertyKeysIterator = propertyKeysList.iterator();
    regularEvents = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(propertyKeysIterator.hasNext()){
        regularEvents.add((String)propertyKeysIterator.next());
    }

    propertyKeysList =  propertiesConfiguration.getList("consolidated");
    propertyKeysIterator = propertyKeysList.iterator();
    consolidatedEvents = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(propertyKeysIterator.hasNext()){
        consolidatedEvents.add((String)propertyKeysIterator.next());
    }

    propertyKeysList =  propertiesConfiguration.getList("correlated");
    propertyKeysIterator = propertyKeysList.iterator();
    correlatedEvents = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(propertyKeysIterator.hasNext()){
        correlatedEvents.add((String)propertyKeysIterator.next());
    }

}
```

whereby I am using the `Apache Commons Configuration` library version 1.10 to read a properties file that has non-unique keys.  I don't receive this error using a JBoss 6.4.8 purpose-built WAR but this error is generating on a JBoss converted 5.2 WAR.

I am using the Apache Commons Lang 2.1 so I'm not sure how `org/apache/commons/lang/text/StrLookup` can be a problem.  All relevant *.java and *.class files have been copied into the converted jar file and everything is fine except this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Note that NoClassDefFoundError is different than ClassNotFoundException. The former can mean that the class was found, but during the a static initializer an exception was thrown.

Wrap this method code in a try catch and output the exception. Likely you will see why.

Comment: The method invocation `readPropertyFile() ` is already wrapped in a try/catch but I am unable to see the output when the `NoClassDefFoundError` error pops.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some dependent jar was present at compile time but missing at runtime. Can you compare classpaths for  build time and runtime. It will give you the difference which jar is missing and causing this issue.

Comment: Using Elcipse Juno, how might I accomplish this or do I need to look into my Windows classpath and compare that to mu build classpath in Eclipse Juno?

Comment: Check the jar files you have in your war file and compare them with the jar files present in your project.

Comment: I know the problem is with Apache-Commons Configuration and the jar file is present within my project.  As I couldn't determine what additional jars were needed, I opted to write code to read non-unique properties in a property file.